# Не очищается переменная htmlentities из формы пользователя

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Не могу понять почем не преобразовывается переменная при внесении в базу данных.

Использую Red Bean PHP в котором сказано было что он якобы защищает от Sql атак, но оказывается нет, данные попадают в чистом виде в базу, к примеру если в поле написать `<script>` то так он и будет занесен.

Форма.

```
 <form name="Download" id="Download" method="post" action="T.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" name="text">
    
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file."> 


</form>
```

Обработчик

```
<?php 

$data = $_POST;


if(isset($data['submit']))            { 
 

$text = htmlentities($text);



//Указали таблицу
          $ads = R::dispense('rent');

// Внесли переменную
          $ads->text = $data['text'];
         
// Сохранили в таблицу

          R::store($ads);
 
         echo "Вы успешно зарегистрировались";


}
else {
  exit('No');  
}


 ?>
```

Пробовала ловить переменную так

```
$text = $data($text);
```

и так

```
$text = $data['text'];
```

и вот так

```
  $clean = $data['text'];
  $clean = htmlentities($clean);
  $text = $clean;
```

Ничего в итоге не получается.

Вот этот код примера работает в обычном PHP редакторе онлайн, а вот как это преобразовать в форме, пока не могу понять.

```
$text = '<script>';

$clean = htmlentities($text);

echo $clean;
```

Comment: Для начала стоит разобраться что такое sql-инъекция, а потом понять что htmlentites __не предназначен__ для защиты от sql-инъекций.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто, главное не переживайте, у всех бывают неудачи при обучении.

Ответ был очень близок.

Вам нужно было спуститься на уровень внесения переменной в Базу данных, тогда все получится.

Где комментарий // Внесли переменную следует вставить следующую строчку

```
$ads->text = htmlentities($data['text']);
```

Весь код целиком

```
    <?php 
    
    $data = $_POST;
    
    
    if(isset($data['submit']))            { 
     
       
    
    //Указали таблицу
              $ads = R::dispense('rent');
    
   
 // Внесли переменную

             $ads->text = htmlentities($data['text']);
             
   
 // Сохранили в таблицу
    
              R::store($ads);
     
             echo "Вы успешно зарегистрировались";
    
    
    }
    else {
      exit('No');  
    }
    
    
     ?>
```

Удачи!